# Fluid increase speed over time

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have my fluid physics setup like so

[image: blender water physics settings]

How can I increase the "speed" over the course of the animation? I'm trying to mimic a garden hose being turned on.

Comment: Please show your inflow objects.

Comment: Domain suggestion.  Consider turning up your resolution final value.  Consider turning down your resolution preview value if you never use it. Depending on your hardware.

Comment: Do you mean the speed of the fluid ... thus volume/time?  You might possibly mean speed up of playback of simulation or video editing.

Answer (score 1):

You fluid simulation inflow has a

inflow velocity

this value can be animated with keyframes. You can increase or decrease velocity.

As well you may turn off the inflow with the enabled value.

[image]